# Type mismatch: inferred type is V? but Collection<Nothing> was expected

Tags: generics, kotlin

```
fun someMethod(v: Any) {
    val fieldValue = get(Any())

    if (fieldValue != null && fieldValue is MutableCollection<*> && v is Collection<*>) {
        fieldValue.addAll(v)
    }
}

fun get(obj: Any): Any? {
    TODO()
}
```

The code above returns the following error:

> Error:(115, 39) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is V? but
>   Collection was expected. Projected type MutableCollection<*>
>   restricts use of public abstract fun addAll(elements: Collection):
>   Boolean defined in kotlin.collections.MutableCollection

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the intended behaviour for star projection with invariant type `T`, as in `MutableCollection<T>`. From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections):

> For Foo<T : TUpper>, where T is an invariant type parameter with the upper bound TUpper, Foo<*> is equivalent to Foo<out TUpper> for reading values and to Foo<in Nothing> for writing values.

Why is it like that?
In Java when you have a `List<?>` you can always insert `null` as all types are nullable, but the same is not true in Kotlin, that's why you can't add anything to `MutableList<*>`. Similarly, whatever you extract from a Java `List<?>` will always be a subtype of `Object` (because every non-primitive type extends `Object`). In Kotlin you know that whatever you extract from a `MutableList<*>` will always be a subtype of `TUpper` (or `Any?`, if you don't specify an upper bound, because that is the most "generic" type available).